# Scrollbar in tkinter doesn't appear (using .place)

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

I am trying to add a scrollbar to my GUI and found a pretty nice tutorial on [youtube](https://youtu.be/0WafQCaok6g). Even when he uses `pack` in the code, there is a comment which translates the code to make it able to use it with `place`. I made a few adaptions but it didn't work, only the (non-functional) arrows and the background of the scrollbar appear [as you can see here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/udD6c.png). I've tried some other solutions in SO like

[Scrollbar in Canvas doesn't work - Tkinter Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70680456/scrollbar-in-canvas-doesnt-work-tkinter-python)

[Tkinter scrollbar not appearing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57173384/tkinter-scrollbar-not-appearing)

So here is what I tried so far:

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk

window1.destroy()  # previous window where user enters meta data
input_window= tk.Tk()
input_window.geometry(str(width) + 'x' + str(height))  # height=840, width=480
# Adding a Full Screen ScrollBar - Python Tkinter GUI Tutorial #96 https://youtu.be/0WafQCaok6g">
# Create canvas
my_canvas = tk.Canvas(input_window, width=width, height=height)
my_canvas.place(x=0, y=0)
# creating frame
main_frame = tk.Frame(my_canvas, width=width, height=height)
main_frame.place(x=0, y=0)

# Add A Scrollbar To The Canvas
my_scrollbar = ttk.Scrollbar(input_window, orient='vertical', command=my_canvas.yview)
my_scrollbar.place(x=width-20, y=0, height=height)
# Configure The Canvas
my_canvas.configure(yscrollcommand=my_scrollbar.set)
my_canvas.bind('<Configure>', lambda e: my_canvas.configure(scrollregion=my_canvas.bbox("all")))

def _on_mouse_wheel(event):  # scrolling mousewheel
    my_canvas.yview_scroll(-1 * int((event.delta / 120)), "units")

my_canvas.bind_all("<MouseWheel>", _on_mouse_wheel)

# Create ANOTHER Frame INSIDE the Canvas
second_frame = tk.Frame(my_canvas, width=width, height=height)
# Add that New frame To a Window In The Canvas
my_canvas.create_window((0, 0), window=second_frame, anchor="nw")

...

window1.mainloop()  # previous window
```

My guess is, that the window is larger than the height of 840 because I can only see the upper arrow of the grey scrollbar. If I enlarge the window I can see the lower arrow of the gray scrollbar but the bar never appears.

Thanks in advance for your help!

Comment: Your problems are entirely due to using `.place()`.  With either `.pack()` or `.grid()`, you can trivially tell the scrollbar to occupy the exact available height of the window, without having to guess at how many pixels shorter you have to make it to adjust for the height of the title bar.  The non-functionality of the scroll bar is due to never settings the Canvas `scrollregion`; you've added a binding to automatically set it when the Canvas resizes, but a widget added via `.place()` doesn't automatically resize.  You also need to set `scrollregion`  once at startup.

Comment: Thank you for the comment! So if I understand you right, I have to firstly rewrite everything and use `.pack()` or `.grid()` instead of `.place()`? Which honestly would take a long time because almost everything is based on relative `.place()` relations. Secondly you suggest to preallocate `scrollregion` but can you tell me where and how? Why isn't it enough to set it in the part where the scrollbar is added to the canvas?

Comment: You need to bind `<Configure>` on `internal_frame` instead of `my_canvas` because adding widgets to `internal_frame` does not change the size of `my_canvas`.  Also what is the usage of `main_frame`? The scrollbar is not active because the size of `second_frame` is around the same as `my_canvas`. Try changing the height of `second_frame` to a larger value.

Comment: Your first hint worked, I've changed `my_canvas.bind('<Configure>', lambda e: my_canvas.configure(scrollregion=my_canvas.bbox("all")))` to `my_canvas.bind('<Configure>', lambda e: input_window.configure(scrollregion=my_canvas.bbox("all")))` and now I can scroll but the bar itself still doesn't appear. Your 3rd point concerning the height of `second_frame` hasn't any effect. It seems I can also scroll without changing its height. In addition to that python raises an error: `_tkinter.TclError: unknown option "-scrollregion"`

Comment: The usage of `main_frame` is a good question. In the video he didn't mentioned any purpose of `main_frame`. I've commented it out and it is still working. However, I can scroll without any limits up and down and in regions where it makes no sense to scroll into grey regions (where GUI should end).